# String and switch case in Java

Tags: java, string, switch-statement

Please explain the output "0" of the below code sample. And is it legal to use string in switch case statement in Java ?

```
public class Test {

static int x;

public static void main(String[] args) {
    String ss = "aBc";
    String s = "ABC";
    switch (s) {
        case "":
            x++;
        case "AbC":
            x++;
            break;
        case "ABC":
            x--;
        default:
            x++;

    }
    System.out.print(x);
}
```

}

Comment: Is this homework? Whether it's legal depends on the Java version, and odd behaviour may come from missing `break` statements.

Comment: @fastsnail Actually since Java7

Comment: What's the point of having the `ss` variable, when it's never used?

Comment: @MarounMaroun ohh i didn't remember .tnx

Comment: @fastsnail This doesn't make your sentence wrong though.. :)

Comment: What's the point of complaining about a pointless variable in a program in which every line exudes pointlessness?  :) :) :) :)

Comment: @MarounMaroun yes i'm not wrong haha i didn't tell it's illegal in java 7

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, It is legal to use Strings in java unlike C which accepts only integers.

you have `s = "ABC"`, which executes the 3rd and default case since you did not specify `break` in the 3rd case to delimit your switch behavior. Therefore in the `3rd case` value of of x after  x-- results in x = -1 and in the default it is incremented back to 0. so the value of x has not changed from its initial value.

Answer (score 3):

If you didnt add break it will call both case (which is correct) and default.

```
case "ABC" : x--;
default : x++;
```

So it go through the above cases

Answer (score 2):

You didn't put a break after case "ABC", so the default was probably executed as well. Default x = 0, and these lines of the switch statement was executed:

```
case "ABC" : x--;
default : x++;
```

So, x=0, then x=-1 after the first line, and x = 0, after the second line.

Comment: `x--` makes `x` go from 0 to 1?  Hmmmm.

Answer (score 2):

You're hitting two cases in your `switch`.

```
switch(s){
    case "" : x++;
    case "AbC" : x++; break;
    case "ABC" : x--;
    default : x++;
}
```

You hit the `"ABC"` case because `s = "ABC"`, but you don't `break` from it, which would have caused you to leave the `switch` statement altogether.  Because of this, you also then hit the `default` case.

Because of this, `x` is set to -1 after the `"ABC"` case, but then immediately set to 0 due to the `default` case.

Now, I'm not going to say that your `break` statement was missing from it, since it may very well be intentional.  But this is a good reason to include them, as you may wind up getting aberrant behavior if you don't.

Answer (score 2):

variable `x` is intialized to `0` by default:

```
static int x;
```

is the same as

```
static int x = 0;
```

Then `s = "ABC"` therefore you arrive to `case "ABC"` that makes `x = -1`. However there is no `break` in this case entry, so you continue to `default` that performs `x++`, i.e. `-1 + 1` that is `0`.

Answer (score 0):

You're missing a `break` statement:

```
// x is initialized to zero
// s = "ABC"
switch(s) {
    case "": // Skipped
        x++;
    case "AbC": // Skipped
        x++; 
        break;
    case "ABC":  // This is executed
        x--;     // x is now equal to 1, but there's no break statement
    default:     // Since there's no break statement, this block is also executed
        x++;     // x is now equal to 1--: 0
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
is it legal to use string in switch case statement in Java ?
```

Java 7 introduce switch statement with sting. and it is pretty much legal to use string with switch statement.

Switch case syntax - you are missing `break` in your switch statement

```
switch(expression){
    case value :
       //Statements
       break; //optional
    case value :
       //Statements
       break; //optional
    //You can have any number of case statements.
    default : //Optional
       //Statements
}
```

I have modified Line 1 added `break` keyword, In your code when Line 3 executes first it will change x value 0 to -1 then Line 4 will execute it will change x value -1 to 0, so your result is "0"

```
public class Test {

    static int x;
    public static void main(String[] args) {
    String ss = "aBc";
    String s = "ABC";
    switch(s){
    case "" : x++; break;   // Line 1         
    case "AbC" : x++;break; // Line 2
    case "ABC" : x--;       // Line 3
    default : x++;          // Line 4

    }
    System.out.print(x);
    }    
}
```